# Is there a way to avoid writing inline views more than once in MySQL

Tags: mysql, inline-view

Consider a Student table, and a Grades table. Grades table has grades for all the courses that the student took. I want to find the student who has the maximum average grade.

I would have used CTE for this problem, but it seems that MySQL doesn't provide CTE.
I want to write a single query to find the student with maximum avg. grade, also avoiding writing the query, that gets avg. grades of all students, more than once.

A query that doesn't work is as follows (this might give more idea what I want to achieve):

```
select temp.st_name 
from (select st1.student_name st_name, AVG(grade) avg_grade from Student st1, Grades grd1 where st1.student_id = grd1 .student_id group by st1.student_id,  st1.sudent_name) temp 
where temp.avg_grade = (select MAX(temp.avg_grade) from temp)
```

The above query gives the error: Table temp doesn't exist.

Is there any other way I can find the student with maximum avg. grade, avoiding to write inline-view statement twice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. Your options are to copy/paste that bad-boy into another subquery or create an actual view to query against.

Comment: I was hoping I will not have to hear this :(
Thanks for your reply!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you could use ORDER BY with LIMIT, but I never wrote any MYSQL so I might be wrong ;)

```
SELECT
    st1.student_name st_name,
    AVG(grade) avg_grade
FROM Student st1, Grades grd1
WHERE st1.student_id = grd1 .student_id
GROUP BY 
    st1.student_id,
    st1.sudent_name
ORDER BY avg_grade DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

*Note: I haven't changed your initial statement, but you should be using the JOIN syntax over FROM tbl1, tbl2*

Comment: Actually this will probably work. Didn't read the problem carefully enough and only focused on the "can you CTE in MySQL" part. Nice solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't think this is going to work if there are more than one students with the maximum average grade.

Comment: @NitinYadav, Well in that case you have no other choice than perform a query of query.